# Show that $X_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}$ and $X_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \rho^{k}$ are Cauchy sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

Show that $X_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}$  and $X_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \rho^{k}$ are Cauchy sequences.

I know that for each sequence I have to show the following:

"$\forall \epsilon>0 \text{   }\exists \text{   } N_{\epsilon}=N(\epsilon) \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n \geq N_{\epsilon}$ ,        $ \left | X_{n}-X_{m} \right | < \epsilon $"

1) For the first I have done the following:

$\left | X_{n}-X_{m} \right |=\left | \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^{m} \frac{1}{k!} \right |=  \left | \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} \frac{1}{k!}\right | $

After this I want to use the fact that $\frac{1}{k!}\leq \frac{1}{2k}$ for $k\geq 3$, suppose that $m\geq n$, and get:

$=  \left | \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} \frac{1}{k!}\right | \leq \left | \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} \frac{1}{2k}\right |=\left | \frac{1}{2(n+1)}+\frac{1}{2(n+2)}+\cdots +\frac{1}{2(m)}\right |$

then I have to bound this with a value that depends on n, on which I will impose that it is less or equal to $\epsilon$ and deduct the value of $N_{\epsilon}$ from there.

my guess so far is $\frac{m-n}{n}<\frac{m}{n} <\epsilon$

but this wont work because it is too big and I it should be "sufficiently" small (smaller than $\epsilon$).

2) For the second sequence I have done the following:

Since $0<\rho<1 \Rightarrow \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\rho^{k}=\frac{1}{1-\rho}=l $, then we have that

"$\forall \frac{\epsilon}{2}>0 \text{   }\exists \text{   } N'_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}=N'(\frac{\epsilon}{2}) \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $\forall n \geq N'_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$ ,        $ \left | \sum_{k=0}^{n} \rho^{k}-l \right | < \frac{\epsilon}{2} $"

Let  $ \epsilon>0$,    I choose $N_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}=N'_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$ .
We want to show that  $N_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$  works.

$\text{  if  } n,m\geq N_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}} \Rightarrow$

$\left | X_{n}-X_{m} \right |=\left | \sum_{k=0}^{n} \rho^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{m} \rho^{k}\right |< \left | \sum_{k=0}^{n} \rho^{k}-l+l-\sum_{k=0}^{m} \rho^{k}\right | \leq \left | \sum_{k=0}^{n} \rho^{k}-l\right |+\left | \sum_{k=0}^{m} \rho^{k}-l \right |<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$.

$\therefore N_{\frac{\epsilon}{2}} $ works.

Could you give me any suggestions for the first sequence? 
Is the second demonstration correct?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first we have that $\frac {1}{k!}<\frac {1}{k^2}$ for $k\geq 4$ and thus $\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} \frac {1}{k!}\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} \frac {1}{k^2}$ and $\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} \frac {1}{k^2}$ converges and so the sequence $x_m=\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} \frac {1}{k^2}$ is Cauchy, and thus $y_m=\sum_{k=n+1}^{m} \frac {1}{k!}$ is upper bounded by a Cauchy sequence,so $x_m$ is Cauchy(do your thing with $ε>0$).

For the second well done. But these sums converge and so there are Cauchy.You don't have to show that they are Cauchy with definition,unless you've benn asked too:)

Comment: Thank you, this was very useful!! yes I have to use the definition.

Answer (score 1):

For the first series: $X_{n} = \sum^{n}_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!} $ you could use the following approximation:
$$
\left| X_{n} - X_{m} \right| = \left| \sum^{n}_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!} - \sum^{m}_{k=0} \frac{1}{k!} \right| = \left| \sum^{m}_{k=n+1} \frac{1}{k!} \right| \leq \left| \sum^{m}_{k=n+1} \frac{1}{e^{k}} \right|
$$
for a all value of $n$ and  $m$ greater than $ n_{0}$ (say $n_{0} =10$, i'm lazy and this seams a good enough aproximation ) . Now this could be written as 
$$
\left| \sum^{m}_{k=n+1} \frac{1}{e^{k}} \right| = \left| \sum^{m}_{k=n+1} e^{-k}  \right| = \left| e^{-(n+1)} \sum^{m-(n+1)}_{k=0} e^{-k}  \right|
$$
Now you can see there first term will drop to infinity and the second series is finite and bound above by
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}  \sum^{m}_{k=n+1} e^{-k}   = \frac{1}{1-e^{-1}}
$$
This leads to the final expression 
$$
\left| X_{n} - X_{m} \right| =  \leq \left| \sum^{m}_{k=n+1} \frac{1}{e^{k}} \right| \leq   \frac{e^{-(n+1)}}{1-e^{-1}}
$$
From here on it isn't difficult to produce an $\epsilon - \delta$ proof.
i.e. Take $\epsilon > 0$ random and $n$ so that
$$
n > \max \left( n_{0},\log(\epsilon(1-e^{-1}))-1 \right)
$$ 
And so on. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I would have never thougth of this. It's an interesting way to solve it!